# Should the AngularJS application send the AuthToken or IDToken? When do use ID token vs Auth Token?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi, auth-token

I have the following configuration in my ASP.NET Core Web API:

```
// Adds Microsoft Identity platform (AAD v2.0) support to protect this Api
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration);

services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim("email")
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

I have an Angular client application that sends the AuthToken with each request.

Below is my asp.net WEB API controller

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //Get User Email ID from Claims
        //Get User details from Database
        //Return the User Details
        ...
    }
}
```

In the asp.net WEB API controller, I need to get the Email claim from the Auth Token.

Should the AngularJS application send the AuthToken or IDToken? When do use ID token vs Auth Token?

**Update :**
OpenID Connect is built on top of OAuth2.

**WEBAPI:**
An access_token is useful to call certain APIs in Auth0 (e.g. /userinfo) or an API you define in Auth0.

**WEBAPP:**
An id_token is a JWT and represents the logged in user. It is often used by your app.

**CONSOLE/MOBILE APP** :
A refresh_token (only to be used by a mobile/desktop app) doesn't expire (but is revokable) and it allows you to obtain freshly minted access_tokens and id_token

My question still remains the same? If the webapp or console app requires the claims, should we need AuthToken?

**Update:#2**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4JIvUIE17c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that, [**access tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) are used to perform actions like authentication and authorization to protect the web APIs.

[**ID tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) are generated by authorization server and contains the claim of the user information, and these claims can be used for the UX in your application.

*****AFAIK** as your application sends the `AuthToken` with each request you can use the same token to get Email claim.***

Make sure to add **email** API permissions like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Api Permissions*

[image]

Try to give the `scope = api://{app id of the AAD app which represents the web api}/.default openid` as mentioned by **Allen Wu** in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128383/cant-get-email-claim-in-access-token-in-azure-ad).

*I tried to generate an access token with above scope and got the claims successfully like below:*

[image]

**Please note that, you can get the email claim either by using AuthToken or IDToken.**